# Backsubstituting solution into FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a system of equations which is dependent to an parameter `alpha`. So I iterate over `alpha` via a `Table` call and try to back substitute the solution found in iteration `i` into the `FindRoot` call. My example leads to an infinite recursion.

```
sols = {x -> 0, y -> 0}
Table[ {sol = FindRoot[{alpha x == 0, y x = 3 }, sol[[1, 2]], {alpha, 1, 10}]
```

Heike’s suggestion works perfectly for one parameter.

I tried to extend this for two parameters, but I failed.

```
sols = {x -> 0, y -> 0}
eqns := {alpha x == 0, y x = 3}
Table[sol = FindRoot[eqns, {x, sol[[1, 2]], y, sol[[3, 4]]}], {alpha, 1, 10}]
```

how can I access the solution of `y` correctly?

Comment: two syntax errors in your current code: First, `sol` does not have part `[[3,4]]`. The parts for the values of `x` and `y` are `sol[[1,2]]` and `sol[[2,2]]`, respectively. Second, the second argument of `FindRoot` should be list of lists, e.g., `{{x,0.},{y,.5}}`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use **`FoldList`** or **`NestList`** to use the solution of a step as the starting value for the next step. Please check the documentation on these two functions for detailed examples of how they are used.

```
  FoldList[FindRoot[{#2 x == 1, y x == #2/2},{{x, #1[[1, 2]]}, {y, #1[[2, 2]]}}] &,
  {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5}, Range@10]
```

It gives:

> ```
> {{x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5}, {x -> 1., y -> 0.5}, {x -> 0.5, y -> 2.}, 
>   {x -> 0.333333, y -> 4.5}, {x -> 0.25, y -> 8.}, {x -> 0.2, y -> 12.5}, 
>   {x -> 0.166667, y -> 18.}, {x -> 0.142857, y -> 24.5}, 
>   {x -> 0.125, y -> 32.}, {x -> 0.111111, y -> 40.5}, {x -> 0.1, y -> 50.}}
> ```

`NestList` is a little more complicated:

```
  NestList[
  {#[[1]] + 1, FindRoot[{(#[[1]] + 1)  x == 1, y x == (#[[1]] + 1)/2}, 
  {{x, #[[2, 1, 2]]}, {y, #[[2, 2, 2]]}}]} &, 
  {0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5}}, 10]
```

which produces

> ```
>  {{0, {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5}}, {1, {x -> 1., y -> 0.5}}, {2, {x -> 0.5,y -> 2.}}, 
>    {3, {x -> 0.333333, y -> 4.5}}, {4, {x -> 0.25, y -> 8.}}, 
>    {5, {x -> 0.2, y -> 12.5}}, {6, {x -> 0.166667, y -> 18.}}, 
>    {7, {x -> 0.142857, y -> 24.5}}, {8, {x -> 0.125, y -> 32.}}, 
>    {9, {x -> 0.111111, y -> 40.5}}, {10, {x -> 0.1, y -> 50.}}}
> ```

You can get the second parts of the rows by adding the following code at the end:

```
  NestList[...] // Last /@ # &
```

Answer (score 3):

When you put

```
sols={};
```

then calling

```
 FindRoot[alpha x == 1, Drop[sols, Length[sols]]
```

you get

```
FindRoot::fdss: "Search specification {} should be a list with 1 to 5 elements."
```

because the second argument in FindRoot does not have one of the expected forms :
neither `FindRoot[alpha x == 1, x]` nor `FindRoot[alpha x == 1, {x,x0}]`,  where `x0` denotes the point where `FindRoot` starts to find a numerical solution. Consequentely you get this message

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 256 exceeded
```

because the variable does not have a value, even `FindRoot` doesn't know with respect to which variable to solve  equations.

**Edit**

When you deal with two variables to be found, you can proceed along this route :

```
sol  = {x -> 0.5, y -> 0.5};
sols = Table[ FindRoot[ {alpha x == 1, y x == alpha/2}, 
                       {{x, sol[[1, 2]]}, {y, sol[[2, 2]]}}],
              {alpha, 1, 10}];
sols
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1.,      y -> 0.5 }, {x -> 0.5, y -> 2.  }, {x -> 0.333333, y -> 4.5}, 
> {x -> 0.25,     y -> 8.  }, {x -> 0.2, y -> 12.5}, {x -> 0.166667, y -> 18.}, 
> {x -> 0.142857, y -> 24.5}, {x -> 0.125, y -> 32.},
> {x -> 0.111111, y -> 40.5}, {x -> 0.1,   y -> 50.}}
> ```

Otherwise, putting initial values where e.g. `sol = {x -> 0, y -> 0};` `FindRoot` fails because the system is singular. 
In order to track evaluating of an expression, it recommended to use `Trace`, e.g. :

```
Table[ FindRoot[ { alpha x == 1, y x == alpha/2 }, 
       {{ x, sol[[1, 2]] }, { y, sol[[2, 2]] }}  ],
       {alpha, 1, 10}] // Trace
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
sol = {x -> 0};
sols = Table[sol = FindRoot[alpha x == 1, {x, sol[[1, 2]]}], {alpha, 1, 10}]
```